# Compiling gsl library. Error appears: zsh: exec format error: ./compute.o

Tags: c++, g++, gnu, gsl

I'm trying to install and compile an "easy" c++ code including the GNU Scientific Library.
Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h"
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = 5.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);

    printf("J0 (%f) = %f\n", x, y);

    return 0;

}
```

Now, I want to compile this code with the following command
line:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/ compute.cc
```

This generates a **compute.o** file.
So far so good. But when I try to execute this file my Mac shows the following problem:

```
zsh: exec format error: ./compute.o
```

I ask you for help and would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you trying to run an object file?  Are you familiar with the steps of building a C++ application, i.e. compilation **+ linking**  = executable/library?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'am very sorry. Unfortunately, i'm not very familiar with building a C++ application. Nevertheless, do you maybe have a suggestion for me?

Comment: Using `g++` and the linker `ld` are explained in many tutorials, better than trying to put everything into an answer on StackOverflow.  Maybe you should start smaller first, a simple "Hello World" program, instead of jumping into trying to get third-party libraries to work.

Answer (score 0):

The command to create the executable:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/ compute.cc -o compute
```

without the `-c` and with `-o <name of program>`. And you have to link with the needed libraries:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/ compute.cc -o compute -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

as explained in the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html#compiling-and-linking).